How to simulate a current zero crossing in LTspice
I'm designing a flexible AC transmission system that utilises TSR.I'll need to use a voltage zero crossing and current zero crossing in my circuit to send to the microcontroller. I've being playing around with zero crossings in LTspice and I'm curious as to how I would design a current zero crossing and how I would simulate that in LTspice to measure the current. For the current zero crossing I will have a 230V load connected to a CT which is then run through to the zero crossing.


Can you explain the relevance of the image please?

A CT with a load resistor is a relatively low-impedance voltage source and you can feed it to a comparator, same as detecting a voltage zero-crossing.
If you need to simulate the CT itself, you just set up two inductors of specific inductances and set up the coupling between them with a SPICE directive. Simple, and there are plenty of tutorials online.
